# Steam on Ubuntu 18.04 on Virtaul Box

Tags: virtualbox, steam, ubuntu-18.04

I want to run steam on Ubuntu 18.94 on virtualbox. I can download it but it doesn't open. This is the error I got when trying to open on terminal

`Running Steam on ubuntu 18.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0)
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast`